# How to know which jquery version can i use with codeigniter 2.1.0?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am using the `CodeIgniter 2.1.0` with `jquery 1.8.2`, I want to upgrade the jquery version for security measures. How can I know which version can I use, with my version of CodeIgniter, without breaking my code?

Comment: You can use any version you like, codeigniter itself does not depend on jQuery. However any code you've written may use deprecated methods. The easiest way to check is to upgrade the version and see what breaks by running your test suite

Comment: Yes, you can ANY version of jQuery it doesn't depend upon which framework or version you are using.

Comment: If you are upgrading to improve security please consider using the current version of CodeIgniter which is [3.1.9](https://codeload.github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/zip/3.1.9)